# MYSQL - MAX() and GROUP BY() not results as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

after running an sql

```
SELECT 
        m.stdClassID,
        m.Percentage,
        sc.ClassID,
        sc.Form,
        sc.FormName,
        sc.Year,
        sc.stdName
FROM stdremark  m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        sc.ClassID,
        c.Form,
        c.FormName,
        sc.stdClassID,
        c.Year,
        CONCAT(s.StdFname,' ',s.StdLname) as stdName
    FROM tblstdclass sc 
    INNER JOIN tblclass c
        ON sc.ClassID=c.ClassID
    INNER JOIN tblstudents s
        ON sc.StdID = s.StdID
    WHERE c.Year=2018
) sc ON m.stdClassID=sc.stdClassID
WHERE m.Term=3`
```

I come up with this result
I want to get the maximum percentage of each student grouped by the Form column

[image: result of sql]

when I try to get Max() and group by()
from the sql:

```
SELECT 
        m.stdClassID,
        MAX(m.Percentage),
        sc.ClassID,
        sc.Form,
        sc.FormName,
        sc.Year,
        sc.stdName
FROM stdremark  m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        sc.ClassID,
        c.Form,
        c.FormName,
        sc.stdClassID,
        c.Year,
        CONCAT(s.StdFname,' ',s.StdLname) as stdName
    FROM tblstdclass sc 
    INNER JOIN tblclass c
        ON sc.ClassID=c.ClassID
    INNER JOIN tblstudents s
        ON sc.StdID = s.StdID
    WHERE c.Year=2018
) sc ON m.stdClassID=sc.stdClassID
WHERE m.Term=3
GROUP BY sc.Form`
```

[image: but what am actually getting as result is]

the expected result should have been

```
17     71     28     upper     Science     2018     Jerry Maguire
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: To add to @GordonLinoff 's comment Sample data and desired results as formatted text not as images

Comment: first: do not use same alias (`sc`) for different elements in same query (tblstdclass and resultset of join). even if it does work, it will be confusing. Second, as far as I remember, MySQL in recent versions does enforce the use of an aggregate function or group by for every single field you select, precisely to avoid problems like this, ie you no longer can use max() on one field, group by on another, and then select a few more fields. every field either has to be in an aggregate function of has to be in group by.

Answer (score 2):

Could be an issue with MySQL allowing partial grouping. Try to extend your `GROUP BY` expression to group on all columns, except `m.Percentage`.

```
...
GROUP BY m.stdClassID,
         sc.ClassID,
         sc.Form,
         sc.FormName,
         sc.Year,
         sc.stdName
```

Other DBMS would force you to do so anyway.

Comment: So does MySQL since version 5.7.5. Since then it has the SQL mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on by default. OP either has disabled that SQL mode or is using an out-of-date version of MySQL.